# No observations after using shp2dta to transform shapefiles

Tags: stata

I wish to create a map of districts in Nepal.

I downloaded the respective shapefiles titled `NP_75DWGS84` from [ArcGIS](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d4ad6faa446b42bd9f1d42407db7b5ba) and proceeded to use the following Stata command:

```
cd "$original_dta/NP_75DWGS84"

shp2dta using NP_75DWGS84, database(data) coordinates(coord) genid(id) replace
```

However, once I ask for the data to be described the following output comes up:

```
Contains data
  obs:             0                          
 vars:             0                          
 size:             0                          
Sorted by:
```

Any idea why the observations are being deleted?

Comment: I don't see what can be checked unless the dataset is publicly accessible.

Comment: The data may be found in the following link: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d4ad6faa446b42bd9f1d42407db7b5ba

Comment: I've fixed after double checking my data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `shp2dta` is *community-contributed* and can be downloaded from SSC:

```
. ssc install shp2dta
```

With the (unzipped) [data](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d4ad6faa446b42bd9f1d42407db7b5ba)  located in Stata's working folder, the syntax:

```
. shp2dta using NP_75DWGS84, database(data) coordinates(coord) genid(id) replace
type: 5
```

creates the following two datasets there:

1. data.dta
2. coord.dta

However, it does not automatically load any of them:

```
. describe

Contains data
  obs:             0                          
 vars:             0                          
 size:             0                          
Sorted by:
```

You just need to do this yourself with `use`:

```
. use data.dta

. describe

Contains data from data.dta
  obs:            75                          
 vars:             8                          
 size:         3,450                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DIST_ID         byte    %10.0g                DIST_ID
DISTRICT        str14   %14s                  DISTRICT
ZONE_NAME       str10   %10s                  ZONE_NAME
REGION          str11   %11s                  REGION
DISS            byte    %10.0g                DISS
Xc              float   %9.0g                 Xc
Yc              float   %9.0g                 Yc
id              byte    %12.0g                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: id

. use coord.dta

. describe

Contains data from coord.dta
  obs:       337,488                          
 vars:             3                         
 size:     5,737,296                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_ID             byte    %12.0g                
_X              double  %10.0g                
_Y              double  %10.0g                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: _ID
```